# What does "concept offering" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

From the bio for the band "Mastodon" on Spotify ([Link](https://open.spotify.com/artist/1Dvfqq39HxvCJ3GvfeIFuT)):

> Their second album, 2004's Leviathan, was a `concept offering` based on Moby Dick, Herman Melville's iconic novel of whaling and obsession, and proved the band's commercial and critical breakthrough.

I've googled the phrase but did not get any satisfying results. Does it literally mean "the offering of a concept"? Even if it does I do not really grasp what the author meant. The album offers a concept of what?

I could even imagine that it is a grammatical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The album was an offering (to the public) based on the concept (idea) of *Moby Dick.*

@KillingTime has provided [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_album) to a definition of the 'concept album'.

Comment: You might want to include an explanation of what a [concept album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_album) is.

Answer (score 1):

"offering" is jargon used by art and music critics. It refers an artistic product that is (offered) for sale or presentation to the public.

A concept album is one that has a theme. The tracks are supposed to supplement one-another rather than to be about disparate subjects.

EDIT

I see that @Kate Bunting has expanded their answer so mine is perhaps superfluous.

Comment: For the benefit of those who will come to this page later, it should be emphasised that both words are used in the quoted text as parts of a **jargon**, and that outside of that jargon, the phrase would have no obvious meaning.